# Udf in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have to call a UDF having argument as another UDF. Eg:

```
Select dataset.udf1(arg1, udf2)
```

What is the correct syntax?

I tried this (not working):

```
Select dataset.udf1(arg1, 
(select string_agg(f,") as h from (select un from 
(select arrray_agg(cast(udf2 as int64))as a), unnest(a) as un
)as f))
```

It is giving error

> correlated subquery that reference another table are not supported unless they can be decorrelated such as transforming them int into an efficient join

Comment: Did you try to set the UDF2 in a `with` and then to use the result as 2nd argument of your UDF1?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, Thanks for responding. Well, both the UDFs are seperate persistent UDF, it is an buisness requirements. So, I have deployed both UDFs seperately in bigquery. And now I have a query in which I have to write....... select udf1(arg1, (outcome of udf2)) like select udf1(arg1, (select udf2(arg2))).....so, basically now I can only call the function not define it using " with" . Please guide

Comment: Can you share the signature of your functions?

Comment: Create function dataset.udf1(a date, b int64)....it returns a integer.                                                                               Create function dataset.udf2(A1 string).....it return an integer (int64).                                                                        Now I am creating a view in which it is like.......                                   Create view dataset.v1(...   .....some fields.....) As           select x.a, x.b , x.c from(select a1 as a, b1 as b, dataset.udf1(date(2023,06,06), (select * from dataset.udf2("abc"))) as c from dataset.table1) x;

Comment: Is your query return only one result in the int64 format?

Comment: If you are talking about udf2, then yes.

Comment: Both UDF return int64.